# data in body not getting passed while consuming rest post web service in my custom drupal module

Tags: php, rest, drupal-6

i created a drupal 8 module meant to submit a form to consume a third party api and display the result on the page. (the api works properly)
When the module is enabled and the url is launched and the form is submited i get the below error

```
{"status":1,"response":"Your email or password is incorrect, please contact Autorescue support team.","support":"ol......adebowale@gmail.com","valid":"0","email":"","password":"","type":"POST"}
```

its showing this error because the values submited for email and password are not being sent

I wrote a drupal 8 module in php meant to submit a form to consume a third party api and display the result on the page.
see the code of the module below

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\drupalup_simple_form\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Our simple form class.
 */
class SimpleForm extends FormBase
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId()
    {
        return 'drupalup_simple_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {

        $form['number_1'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('VIN number'),
        ];


        $form['submit'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Fetch Details'),
        ];

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        // $myUrl = "https://www.autorescue.ng/dealer/index.php";
        $myUrl = "https://www.autorescue.ng/dealer/index.php";

        $data = json_encode(array(
            'email' => 'info@mymech.ng',
            'password' => 'mech1000',
            'vin' => $form_state->getValue('number_1')
        ));

        $options = ["http" => ["method" => "POST",
            "header" => ["Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
                "Content-Type: application/form-data",
                "Authorization: Bearer d321cc05-8361-474e-94b0-8e117fbd50fc",
                "Content-Type: application/json"],
            "content" => $data
        ]];



        $context = stream_context_create($options);
// make the request
        $response = file_get_contents($myUrl, false, $context);

        // drupal_set_message($response);
        drupal_set_message($response);


    }

}
```

result is in below url
https://www.mymech.ng/VinCheck

expected JSON result is

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "result": "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"result\":{\"id\":\"0B5FA853\",\"vin\":\"5UXFA13544LU21050\",\"report\":{\"nmvtis\":{\"junkAndSalvageInformation\":[],\"insuranceInformation\":[],\"brandsRecordCount\":0,\"brandsInformation\":[{\"code\":\"00\",\"name\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"No brand exists for the vehicle.\"},{\"code\":\"01\",\"name\":\"Flood damage\",\"description\":\"\\\"Vehicle damaged by freshwater flood (or it is unknown whether the damage was caused by fresh water or salt water).\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"02\",\"name\":\"Fire damage\",\"description\":\"Vehicle damaged by fire.\"},{\"code\":\"03\",\"name\":\"Hail damage\",\"description\":\"Vehicle damaged by hail.\"},{\"code\":\"04\",\"name\":\"Salt water damage\",\"description\":\"Vehicle damaged by saltwater flood.\"},{\"code\":\"05\",\"name\":\"Vandalism\",\"description\":\"Vehicle damaged by vandals.\"},{\"code\":\"06\",\"name\":\"Kit\",\"description\":\"\\\"A Vehicle that has been built by combining a chassis with a different (non-matching VIN) frame engine and body parts. The VIN on the chassis is used as the vehicle's VIN.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"07\",\"name\":\"Dismantled\",\"description\":\"The vehicle can only be sold as parts and cannot be legally driven.\"},{\"code\":\"08\",\"name\":\"Junk\",\"description\":\"The vehicle is incapable of safe operation for use on the roads or highways and has no resale value except as a source of parts or \\\"scrap or the vehicle's owner has irreversibly designated the vehicle\\\" as a source of parts or scrap. This vehicle shall never be titled or \\\"registered. Also known as non-repairable scrapped or destroyed.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"09\",\"name\":\"Rebuilt\",\"description\":\"\\\"The vehicle previously branded \\\"\\\"salvage\\\"\\\" has passed anti-theft and safety inspections or other jurisdiction procedures to ensure the vehicle was rebuilt to required standards. Also known as prior salvage (salvaged).\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"10\",\"name\":\"Reconstructed\",\"description\":\"\\\"A vehicle that has been permanently altered from original construction by removing adding or substituting major components.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"11\",\"name\":\"Salvage\",\"description\":\"\\\"Damage or Not Specified - Any vehicle which has been wrecked\\\" \\\"destroyed or damaged to the extent that the total estimated or actual\\\" cost of parts and labor to rebuild or reconstruct the vehicle to its pre-accident condition and for legal operation on roads or highways exceeds a jurisdiction-defined percentage of the retail value of the vehicle. The retail value of the vehicle is determined by a current edition of a nationally recognized compilation (to include automated data bases) of retail values. Salvage--Damage or Not Specified also includes any vehicle to which an insurance company acquires owner- ship pursuant to a damage \\\"settlement or any vehicle that the vehicle's owner may wish to\\\" \\\"designate as a salvage vehicle by obtaining a salvage title without\\\" \\\"regard to extent of the vehicle's damage and repairs or any vehicle\\\" for which the jurisdiction cannot distinguish the reason the vehicle was designated salvage.\"},{\"code\":\"12\",\"name\":\"Test Vehicle\",\"description\":\"The vehicle is built and retained by the manufacturer for testing.\"},{\"code\":\"13\",\"name\":\"Refurbished\",\"description\":\"\\\"Any vehicle modified by the installation of a new cab and chassis for the existing coach which has been renovated resulting in a vehicle of greater value or a vehicle with a new style.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"14\",\"name\":\"Collision\",\"description\":\"Vehicle damaged by collision.\"},{\"code\":\"15\",\"name\":\"Reserved\",\"description\":\"\\\"Eliminated in favor of code 09. Code 15 was \\\"\\\"Prior Salvage.\\\"\\\"\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"16\",\"name\":\"Salvage Retention\",\"description\":\"The vehicle is branded salvage and is kept by the owner.\"},{\"code\":\"17\",\"name\":\"Prior Taxi\",\"description\":\"Vehicle previously registered as a taxi.\"},{\"code\":\"18\",\"name\":\"Prior Police\",\"description\":\"Vehicle previously registered as a police vehicle.\"},{\"code\":\"19\",\"name\":\"Original Taxi\",\"description\":\"Vehicle is currently registered as a taxi.\"},{\"code\":\"20\",\"name\":\"Original Police\",\"description\":\"Vehicle is currently registered as a police vehicle.\"},{\"code\":\"21\",\"name\":\"Remanufactured\",\"description\":\"Vehicle was reconstructed by the manufacturer.\"},{\"code\":\"22\",\"name\":\"Gray Market\",\"description\":\"\\\"Vehicle was manufactured for use outside of the United States and has been brought into the United States. Brand '22' has been replaced by brands '45' and '46' as of 6\\/25\\/01.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"23\",\"name\":\"Warranty Return\",\"description\":\"\\\"Vehicle returned to the manufacturer because of a breach in the warranty.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"24\",\"name\":\"Antique\",\"description\":\"The vehicle is over 50 years old.\"},{\"code\":\"25\",\"name\":\"Classic\",\"description\":\"\\\"The vehicle is over 20 years old and adheres to other jurisdiction-specific criteria e.g. vehicle make condition etc.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"26\",\"name\":\"Agricultural Vehicle\",\"description\":\"\\\"The vehicle will primarily be operated on private roads for agricultural purposes.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"27\",\"name\":\"Logging Vehicle\",\"description\":\"\\\"The vehicle will primarily be operated on private roads for logging purposes.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"28\",\"name\":\"Street Rod\",\"description\":\"\\\"The vehicle has been modified to not conform with the manufacturer's specifications and the modifications adhere to jurisdiction-specific criteria.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"29\",\"name\":\"\\\"Vehicle Contains Reissued VIN\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"The chassis VIN has been reissued i.e. the same VIN is reused.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"30\",\"name\":\"Replica\",\"description\":\"\\\"A vehicle with a body built to resemble and be a reproduction of another vehicle of a given year and given manufacturer.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"31\",\"name\":\"Totaled\",\"description\":\"\\\"A vehicle that is declared a total loss by a jurisdiction or an insurer that is obligated to cover the loss or that the insurer takes possession of or title to.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"32\",\"name\":\"Owner Retained\",\"description\":\"\\\"A vehicle that has been declared by the insurance company to be a total loss but the owner maintains possession and ownership of the vehicle.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"33\",\"name\":\"Bond Posted\",\"description\":\"\\\"The insurance company has issued a bond on the vehicle because the ownership of the vehicle cannot be proven; this allows the vehicle to be sold and titled. Note: This brand is not valid after January 17 2003.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"34\",\"name\":\"Memorandum Copy\",\"description\":\"\\\"The title document is a facsimile title and not the active (original or duplicate) title document.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"35\",\"name\":\"Parts Only\",\"description\":\"\\\"The vehicle may only be used for parts. This code is no longer used use '07 - Dismantled'.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"36\",\"name\":\"Recovered Theft\",\"description\":\"\\\"The vehicle was previously titled as salvage due to theft. The Vehicle has been repaired and inspected (or complied with other jurisdiction procedures) and may be legally driven.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"37\",\"name\":\"Undisclosed Lien\",\"description\":\"\\\"The vehicle has entered the titling jurisdiction from a jurisdiction that does not disclose lien-holder information on the title. The titling jurisdiction may issue a new title without this brand if no notice of a security interest in the vehicle is received within a jurisdiction defined timeframe. Note: This brand is not valid after January 17 2003.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"38\",\"name\":\"\\\"Prior Owner Retained\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"A vehicle that was previously branded owner retained and was sold. The new owner's title contains this brand.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"39\",\"name\":\"\\\"Vehicle Non-conformity Uncorrected\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"A non-safety defect reported to the jurisdiction by the vehicle manufacturer remains uncorrected.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"40\",\"name\":\"\\\"Vehicle Non-conformity Corrected\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"A non-safety defect reported to the jurisdiction by the vehicle manufacturer has been corrected.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"41\",\"name\":\"\\\"Vehicle Safety Defect Uncorrected\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"A safety defect reported to the jurisdiction by the vehicle manufacturer remains uncorrected.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"42\",\"name\":\"\\\"Vehicle Safety Defect Corrected\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"A safety defect reported to the jurisdiction by the vehicle manufacturer has been corrected.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"43\",\"name\":\"\\\"VIN replaced by a new state assigned VIN\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"A title should not be issued for the VIN. This brand can be issued for rebuilt vehicles.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"45\",\"name\":\"Gray Market\",\"description\":\"\\\"Vehicle was manufactured for use outside the United States and has been brought into the United States. The vehicle is not in compliance with applicable federal standards.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"46\",\"name\":\"Gray Market\",\"description\":\"\\\"Vehicle was manufactured for use outside the United States and has been brought into the United States. The vehicle is in compliance with applicable federal standards.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"47\",\"name\":\"Manufacturer Buy\",\"description\":\"A vehicle that has been bought back by the manufacturer under Back\\\"jurisdiction -defined regulations or laws such as lemon laws. For\\\" \\\"example the manufacturer could be obligated to buy back the vehicle\\\" when a specified number of repair attempts fails to correct a major \\\"problem on a new vehicle or if a new vehicle has been out of service\\\" for repair for the same problem for a cumulative period of 30 days or \\\"more within one year of purchase.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"48\",\"name\":\"Former Rental\",\"description\":\"Former Rental\"},{\"code\":\"49\",\"name\":\"Salvage--Stolen\",\"description\":\"\\\"Any vehicle the reporting jurisdiction considers salvage because an insurance company has acquired ownership pursuant to a settlement based on the theft of the vehicle.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"50\",\"name\":\"\\\"Salvage--Reasons Other Than Damage or Stolen\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"Any vehicle the reporting jurisdiction considers salvage based on criteria such as abandonment not covered by the Salvage-- Damage or Not Specified and Salvage--Stolen brands. Note.--Percent of damage is not reported with brand code 50.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"51\",\"name\":\"Disclosed Damage\",\"description\":\"\\\"The vehicle has sustained damage to the extent that the damage is required to be disclosed under the jurisdiction's damage disclosure law.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"52\",\"name\":\"Prior Non-\",\"description\":\"A vehicle constructed by repairing a vehicle that has been destroyed Repairable \\/or declared to be non-repairable or otherwise declared to not be Repairedeligible for titling because of the extent of damage to the vehicle but has been issued a title pursuant to state law after falling within this criterion with this brand on the face of the certificate of title.\"},{\"code\":\"53\",\"name\":\"Crushed\",\"description\":\"\\\"The frame or chassis of the vehicle has been crushed or otherwise destroyed so that it is physically impossible to use it in constructing a vehicle.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"55\",\"name\":\"Hazardous substance\",\"description\":\"Hazardous Substance Contaminated Vehicle - The jurisdiction has determined that the vehicle has been contaminated by a \\u2018hazardous substance\\u2019 and is unsafe for use. Excluding flood damaged vehicles.<br><br>A 'hazardous substance' is any substance that could diminish the safety of the vehicle or cause injury to its occupants. The 'hazardous substance' has one or more, but is not limited to the following intrinsic 'hazardous properties':<ul><li>Explosiveness<\\/li><li>Flammability<\\/li><li>Ability to oxidize (accelerate a fire)<\\/li><li>Human toxicity (acute or chronic)<\\/li><li>Corrosiveness (to human tissue or metal)<\\/li><li>Eco toxicity (with or without bioaccumulation)<\\/li><li>Capacity, on contact with air or water, to develop one or more of the above properties.<\\/li><\\/ul>\"},{\"code\":\"68\",\"name\":\"Actual\",\"description\":\"The true mileage for the vehicle. The odometer has not been \\\"tampered with reached its mechanical limits or been altered.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"69\",\"name\":\"Not Actual\",\"description\":\"The odometer reading is known to be other than the true mileage for the vehicle.\"},{\"code\":\"70\",\"name\":\"Not Actual\",\"description\":\"Odometer tampering verified - The odometer reading is known to be \\\"other that the true mileage for the vehicle due to tampering.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"71\",\"name\":\"\\\"Exempt from Odometer Disclosure\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"The vehicle falls within criteria that allow it to change ownership without disclosure of the odometer reading.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"72\",\"name\":\"\\\"Exceeds Mechanical Limits\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"The odometer reading is less than the true mileage of the vehicle because the odometer can not display the total number of true miles.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"73\",\"name\":\"\\\"Odometer may be Altered\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"The titling authority has reason to believe that the odometer reading does not reflect the true mileage of the vehicle because of an alteration to the odometer.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"74\",\"name\":\"Odometer Replaced\",\"description\":\"\\\"The odometer in the vehicle is not the odometer put in the vehicle when manufactured.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"75\",\"name\":\"\\\"Reading at Time of Renewal\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"The odometer reading was recorded when the registration was renewed.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"76\",\"name\":\"\\\"Odometer Discrepancy\\\"\",\"description\":\"\\\"The titling authority has reason to believe that the odometer reading does not reflect the true mileage of the vehicle because of known previous recorded values of odometer for the vehicle.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"77\",\"name\":\"Call Title Division\",\"description\":\"\\\"The titling authority knows of some problem with the odometer reading that it cannot print on a title. Titling authority will discuss the problem (manual process) with authorized inquirers.\\\"\"},{\"code\":\"78\",\"name\":\"\\\"Rectify Previous Exceeds Mechanical Limits Brand\\\"\",\"description\":\"A state other than the brander corrected brand 72.\"},{\"code\":\"90\",\"name\":\"Pending Junk\",\"description\":\"Consumer Assistance to Recycle and Save (CARS) program is Automobile -\\\"processing an application which if approved will render this vehicle\\\" CARS.gov \\\"incapable of operating on public streets roads and highways. The\\\" \\\"vehicle will have no value except as a source of parts or scrap shall\\\" be crushed or shredded within a specified time period (including the \\\"engine block) and shall not be exported prior to crushing or\\\" shredding. For additional information concerning the CARS program visit CARS.gov. Pursuant to the Consumer Assistance to Recycle and Save Act of\"},{\"code\":\"91\",\"name\":\"Junk Automobile -\",\"description\":\"\\\"2009 (CARS) this vehicle is incapable of operating on public streets\\\" CARS.gov\\\"roads and highways. The vehicle has no value except as a source of\\\" \\\"parts or scrap shall be crushed or shredded within a specified time\\\" \\\"period (including the engine block) and shall not be exported prior to\\\"\"}],\"vinChanged\":false,\"currentTitleInformation\":[{\"VehicleIdentification\":{\"IdentificationID\":\"5UXFA13544LU21050\"},\"TitleIssuingAuthorityName\":\"FL\",\"TitleIssueDate\":{\"Date\":\"2003-10-29T00:00:00.000Z\"},\"VehicleOdometerReadingMeasure\":\"000000009\",\"VehicleOdometerReadingUnitCode\":\"M\",\"RecordMatchSequenceID\":\"01\"}],\"historyInformation\":[]},\"decoder\":{\"vin\":\"5UXFA13544LU21050\",\"year\":\"2004 \",\"make\":\"BMW \",\"model\":\"X5 \",\"trim\":\"3.0i \",\"madeIn\":\"UNITED STATES \",\"style\":\"SPORT UTILITY 4-DR \",\"engine\":\"3.0L L6 DOHC 24V \",\"fuelTank\":\"24.30 gallon\",\"cityMileage\":\"15 - 16 miles\\/gallon\",\"highwayMileage\":\"21 miles\\/gallon\",\"antiBrakeSystem\":\"4-Wheel ABS \",\"steeringType\":\"R&P \",\"standardSeating\":\"5 \",\"optionalSeating\":\"\",\"length\":\"183.70 in.\",\"width\":\"73.70 in.\",\"height\":\"69.30 in.\"},\"nada\":{\"retail\":\"4625\",\"tradeIn\":\"2900\",\"roughTradeIn\":\"1175\",\"averageTradeIn\":\"2100\",\"loanValue\":\"2625\",\"uid\":1126456,\"msrp\":\"40300\",\"tradeInValues\":[{\"date\":\"2019-08-01T00:00:00.000Z\",\"value\":\"2900\"},{\"date\":\"2019-07-01T00:00:00.000Z\",\"value\":\"2900\"},{\"date\":\"2019-06-01T00:00:00.000Z\",\"value\":\"2900\"},{\"date\":\"2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z\",\"value\":\"2900\"},{\"date\":\"2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z\",\"value\":\"3125\"}],\"auctionValues\":false},\"nvs\":{\"Export\":[{\"Vin\":\"5UXFA13544LU21050\",\"ExportDate\":\"2008-11-23T00:00:00.000Z\",\"State\":\"FL\",\"date\":\"2008-11-23T00:00:00.000Z\"}]},\"recalls\":[{\"Manufacturer\":\"BAYERISCHE MOTOREN WERKE\",\"NHTSACampaignNumber\":\"03V475000\",\"ReportReceivedDate\":\"Nov 14, 2003\",\"Component\":\"POWER TRAIN:DRIVELINE:DIFFERENTIAL UNIT\",\"Summary\":\"ON CERTAIN SPORT UTILITY VEHICLES, THE BOLTS THAT HOLD THE FRONT DIFFERENTIAL, THE RIGHT OUTPUT SHAFT HOUSING FLANGE AT THE ENGINE, AND THE RIGHT-HAND ENGINE SUPPORT MAY BE INSUFFICIENTLY TIGHTENED. \\r\\n\",\"Conequence\":\"WITH PROLONGED DRIVING, THESE BOLTS COULD BECOME LOOSE, CAUSE DAMAGE TO THE ENGINE AND TRANSMISSION HOUSINGS.  THE RIGHT OUTPUT SHAFT COULD BECOME DISCONNECTED, AFFECTING THE ABILITY TO CONTROL THE VEHICLE, WHICH COULD RESULT IN A CRASH.  \\r\\n\",\"Remedy\":\"DEALERS WILL INSPECT AND RETIGHTEN THE DRIVETRAIN FASTENERS. OWNER NOTIFICATION BEGAN NOVEMBER 28, 2003.    OWNERS SHOULD CONTACT BMW AT 1-800-831-1117.\\r\\n\",\"Notes\":\"CUSTOMERS CAN ALSO CONTACT THE NATIONAL HIGHWAY TRAFFIC SAFETY ADMINISTRATION'S AUTO SAFETY HOTLINE AT 1-888-DASH-2-DOT (1-888-327-4236).\\r\\n\",\"ModelYear\":\"2004\",\"Make\":\"BMW\",\"Model\":\"X5\"},{\"Manufacturer\":\"BAYERISCHE MOTOREN WERKE\",\"NHTSACampaignNumber\":\"04V344000\",\"ReportReceivedDate\":\"Jul 14, 2004\",\"Component\":\"POWER TRAIN:AUTOMATIC TRANSMISSION:CONTROL MODULE (TCM, PCM)\",\"Summary\":\"ON CERTAIN PASSENGER VEHICLES EQUIPPED WITH 8 AND 12 CYLINDER ENGINES, THE DIGITAL ENGINE MANAGEMENT CONTROL  (EMC) UNITS WERE NOT PRODUCED ACCORDING TO SPECIFICATIONS.  \\r\\n\",\"Conequence\":\"AS A RESULT, ENGINE STALLING WILL OCCUR AFTER A SHORT PERIOD OF OPERATION.  THE VEHICLE MAY NOT BE ABLE TO RESTART.  ALSO, A LOSS OF POWER STEERING AND, AFTER REPEATED ACTUATION OF THE BRAKE PEDAL, A LOSS OF BRAKE POWER ASSIST WILL OCCUR.\\r\\nTHESE CONDITIONS  COULD RESULT IN A VEHICLE CRASH.\\r\\n\",\"Remedy\":\"DEALERS WILL INSTALL A NEW DIGITAL ENGINE MANAGEMENT CONTROL UNIT.  THE RECALL BEGAN ON  JULY 16, 2004.  OWNERS SHOULD CONTACT BMW AT 1-800-831-1117.\\r\\n\",\"Notes\":\"CUSTOMERS CAN CONTACT THE NATIONAL HIGHWAY TRAFFIC SAFETY ADMINISTRATION'S AUTO SAFETY HOTLINE AT 1-888-DASH-2-DOT (1-888-327-4236).\\r\\n\",\"ModelYear\":\"2004\",\"Make\":\"BMW\",\"Model\":\"X5\"},{\"Manufacturer\":\"BMW OF NORTH AMERICA, LLC\",\"NHTSACampaignNumber\":\"04V402000\",\"ReportReceivedDate\":\"Aug 13, 2004\",\"Component\":\"FUEL SYSTEM, GASOLINE:DELIVERY:FUEL PUMP\",\"Summary\":\"ON CERTAIN SPORT UTILITY VEHICLES, THE IN-TANK FUEL LINE MAY HAVE BEEN ATTACHED INCORRECTLY.  \\r\\n\\r\\n\",\"Conequence\":\"ENGINE STALLING COULD OCCUR, EVEN THOUGH THE VEHICLE'S FUEL GAUGE INDICATES THAT FUEL IS PRESENT IN THE TANK.  DEPENDING UPON TRAFFIC AND ROAD CONDITIONS, THIS COULD RESULT IN  A CRASH.\\r\\n\\r\\n\",\"Remedy\":\"DEALERS WILL INSPECT THE IN-TANK SUCTION JET PUMP FUEL LINE AND IF NECESSARY, REATTACH ACCORDING TO SPECIFICATIONS.  THIS RECALL BEGAN SEPTEMBER 9, 2004.  OWNERS SHOULD CONTACT BMW AT 1-800-831-1117.\\r\\n\",\"Notes\":\"CUSTOMERS CAN ALSO CONTACT THE NATIONAL HIGHWAY TRAFFIC SAFETY ADMINISTRATION'S AUTO SAFETY HOTLINE AT 1-888-DASH-2-DOT (1-888-327-4236).\",\"ModelYear\":\"2004\",\"Make\":\"BMW\",\"Model\":\"X5\"},{\"Manufacturer\":\"BMW OF NORTH AMERICA, LLC\",\"NHTSACampaignNumber\":\"04V409000\",\"ReportReceivedDate\":\"Aug 18, 2004\",\"Component\":\"POWER TRAIN:CLUTCH ASSEMBLY:PEDAL\\/LINKAGE\",\"Summary\":\"ON CERTAIN PASSENGER VEHICLES WITH 3.0 L ENGINES AND MANUAL TRANSMISSIONS, IF THE VEHICLE IS IN FIRST GEAR, AND MOVING SLOWLY, WITH THE ACCELERATOR PEDAL HELD IN A CONSTANT POSITION OF LOW ENGINE SPEED AND WITH THE CLUTCH PEDAL HELD IN A PARTIALLY DEPRESSED POSITION, ENGINE SPEED MAY INCREASE.  \\r\\n\",\"Conequence\":\"THE VEHICLE COULD ACCELERATE UNEXPECTEDLY, WHICH COULD RESULT IN A CRASH.\\r\\n\",\"Remedy\":\"DEALERS WILL REPROGRAM  THE VEHICLE'S DIGITAL ENGINE MANAGEMENT CONTROL UNIT.  THE RECALL BEGAN ON SEPTEMBER 8, 2004.  OWNERS SHOULD CONTACT BMW AT  1-800-831-1117.\\r\\n\\r\\n\",\"Notes\":\"CUSTOMERS CAN ALSO CONTACT THE NATIONAL HIGHWAY TRAFFIC SAFETY ADMINISTRATION'S AUTO SAFETY HOTLINE AT 1-888-DASH-2-DOT (1-888-327-4236).\\r\\n \",\"ModelYear\":\"2004\",\"Make\":\"BMW\",\"Model\":\"X5\"}]}}}",
    "vin": "5UXFA13544LU21050",
    "support": "oladapoadebowale@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: It's an authentication issue between your code and Autorescue. As the message says, contact their support team if the authentication is not working for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an authentication issue with a 3rd party API

Comment: Hi. Its not an authentication issue because the same call works perfectly in postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

Got result in format below eventually

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "result": "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"result\":\",\"ModelYear\":\"2004\",\"Make\":\"BMW\",\"Model\":\"X5\"}]}}}",
    "vin": "5UXFA13544LU21050",
    "support": "oladapoadebowale@gmail.com"
}
```